# Need help to using a dropdown select list to change dynamic content on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not a programmer by any means and no very little about scripting.  I could really use some help from someone who knows the ins and outs...

I am trying to recreate the actions on the following page:  http://www.redkensalon.com/distributor-locator/

What I would like to happen is for the visitor to see the drop-down menu of states, when they select their state, it brings up the distributors coded for their state (region)

I am using wordpress and can easily add custom CSS and Java but I don't know what I need to do to make this work.

I am currently stuck at this point:  http://norvellpro.com/?page_id=2947

The drop down action is just not functioning so I know it is a scripting issue.

Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Kristi Stewart
krististewart @ att dot net

Answer (score 1):

Try this
**http://jsfiddle.net/cEb9y/1/**

HTML

```
<select name="state_list" id="state_list">
<option value="">Select State</option>
<option value="distributor_alaska">AK &ndash; Alaska</option>
<option value="distributor_alabama">AL &ndash; Alabama</option>
</select>

<div id="distributor_alaska" class="statediv" >
    alaska
</div>

<div id="distributor_alabama" class="statediv" >
    alabama
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.statediv').hide();

    $('#state_list').change(function(){
         var state = $(this).val();
         if(!state) $('statediv').hide();

         var div= $('#' + state );
         div.removeClass('statediv');
         $('.statediv').hide();
         div.addClass('statediv');

         if ( !div.is(':visible') ) div.fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The select box that you want to trigger a change on has the id "state_list". You'll want to add some Javascript to the page that looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('state_list') = function() {
   ... change the HTML of the distributors div here ...
}
```

If possible, you should include this Javascript after the state_list element. That will cause it to be run after that element is created, which is necessary for it to work. If that's not possible, you can make this code a function that is run on document.onload, which is executed after all elements are loaded.